# Configuring ASMX Web Service End Points - web.config

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, web-config, app-config

I have set up references to 2 web services in a separate assembly TestProj.Core.
I reference this Project in a Web Application Project called TestProj.Web.

When I setup the references in TestProj.Core the wizard gave me an app.config and through an application settings section into it.

How do I get these settings to my web app? Copy and paste these into web.config? "Always Copy" the app.config out to the bin directory? Any good articles on mutiple configs?

**UPDATE:**
When I copy and paste it into the applicationSettings of the web.config, I get an error when I debug -
*Unrecognized configuration section applicationSettings/TestProj.Core.Properties.Settings.*

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste is the only way to do it for any app.config in a separate assembly.

Comment: @tyndall: You also have to add the corresponding `configSections`, `sectionGroup` and `section` entries.